# How to manually lock a FileVault encrypted external hard drive stuck in "unlocked"

Tags: mac, encryption, filevault

My FileVault encrypted extrenal hard drive is stuck in "unlocked" mode as verified by Diskutil Cs List. Is there a command to manually lock it?

I believe this issue must have been caused by either the computer shutting off unexpectantly or the drive being ejected improperly which led to the drive being stuck in "unlocked".

Comment: Connect it to a computer you are not signed in on [ideally one that is not yours at all] & test again. FileVault unlocks automatically most of the time, if the account signed in 'belongs to it'.